# How Can I Automatically Separate Time Series Data Based on Set Interval and Summarize Each Subset?

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for a way to take a raw two-minute interval data file of time vs. rainfall depth, many of which are "zero" values:

```
 Date.time <- c("9/26/2014 15:15", 
"9/26/2014 15:12", 
"9/26/2014 15:14", 
"9/26/2014 15:16", 
"9/26/2014 15:18",
"9/26/2014 15:20",
"9/26/2014 15:22",
"9/26/2014 15:24",
"9/26/2014 15:26",
"9/26/2014 15:34",
"9/26/2014 15:36",
"9/26/2014 15:38",
"9/26/2014 15:40",
"9/26/2014 15:42",
"9/26/2014 15:44",
"9/26/2014 15:46")

Rain <- c(0,.05,.1,.03,0,0,.2,0,0,0,0,0,.04,.1,.15,.22)
my.df <- data.frame(Date.time, Rain)
```

Does anyone know how I could lump the "Rain" column into separate categories based on how many zero values preceded it? I would like to label or extract each set of data that are separated by a pre-defined number of minutes or zero values without any data. For instance, if I said that non-zero values separated by 10 minutes or more of time would be considered two separate subsets, then I would like to label them as such or extract summary data of each subset based on that criterion. In that case, the 0.05, .1, .03, and .2 values would be lumped together, because the 0.03 and 0.2 values are separated by only 4 minutes, not ten, and thus are not discretely separate by my arbitrary classification. The next set of non-zeros (0.04, 0.1, 0.15, and 0.22) are separated by ten minutes from the 0.2 value, thus meeting the arbitrary classification threshold. Does anybody have any ideas where I could go from here?

EDIT: I would preferably like to remove the zero values, which is not too difficult:

```
 my.df2 <- subset(my.df, Rain>0)
```

Then, with my.df2, I would like to find when data is within 10 minutes of each other, and cumulatively classify the Rain data as one "event". A conceptual output might look like this:

```
     Date.time     Rain     Event
9/26/2014 15:12     0.05     A
9/26/2014 15:14     0.10     A
9/26/2014 15:16     0.03     A
9/26/2014 15:22     0.20     A
9/26/2014 15:40     0.04     B
9/26/2014 15:42     0.10     B
9/26/2014 15:44     0.15     B
9/26/2014 15:46     0.22     B
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forms a new group if at least k zeros separate it from the prior group. We define an `na.locf` wrapper with the desired default arguments and then use it in the next line to compute `grp`.  `grp` is 1 for the first group, 2 for the next group and so on.  It is NA for positions not belonging to a group.  The key to all this is the `maxgap` argument in `na.locf`:

```
library(zoo)

k <- 3

Rain <- my.df$Rain
Rain[Rain == 0] <- NA
nalocf <- function(x) na.locf(x, maxgap = k, na.rm = FALSE)

grp <- cumsum(diff(!is.na(c(NA, nalocf(Rain)))) > 0) + nalocf(0 * Rain)
na.omit(cbind(my.df, grp))
```

The result in this case is:

```
         Date.time Rain grp
2  9/26/2014 15:12 0.05   1
3  9/26/2014 15:14 0.10   1
4  9/26/2014 15:16 0.03   1
7  9/26/2014 15:22 0.20   1
13 9/26/2014 15:40 0.04   2
14 9/26/2014 15:42 0.10   2
15 9/26/2014 15:44 0.15   2
16 9/26/2014 15:46 0.22   2
```

**Update** Correction.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same grouping, but use the Date.time values themselves in the logic? As in, subtract date/time (i+1) from date/time (i) and find when a certain time has elapsed between non-zero values?

Comment: I am not clear on how zeros vs. non-zeros are supposed to influence this but `tt <- as.POSIXct(my.df$Date.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(tt) > 5))` starts out at 1 and increases by 1 every time a time exceeds the prior time by more than 5 seconds.